# Logstash fail to create report index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a log pattern and filter, please suggest for a match pattern

```
filter {
  grok {
  match => {"message" => "please suggest me a filter"}
  add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
  add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
   }
```

}

2019-03-25 19:30:47  [ERROR] demo.efdms.controller.HomeController - [ip]:172.16.16.1[DeviceInfo]: [message]:Device is not added to inventory

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it.

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s*\[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]\s*%{IPORHOST:host}\s*-\s*\[ip\]:%{IPORHOST:ip}\[DeviceInfo\]:\s*\[message\]:%{GREEDYDATA:message}$
```

I don't think you need the "add_field", as you already have that info in other fields.

Comment: its match but failed to generate an index in elasticsearch

Comment: So then you need to properly configure your logstash output configuration, and make sure you have your index templates in order in your elasticsearch. For this purpose, consider marking this answer as answered and opening a new question providing the pertinent information about your logstash output conf and your elastic search env...which I think would be a better question to ask in another forums more oriented to infrastructure and not code.